# url string stream editing on the fly?

Tags: firefox, script, browser-addons, url

I have a problem with an unnamed 3rd party application (appA).  It has the ability to dynamically link to other applications through a dynamic url link you can setup.  I'm trying to integrate with another 3rd party web app (appB) who uses a "?" to start the query string part of their url.  Unfortunately, appA is substituting the "?" with a " " blank space.  The vendor is uncooperative in resolving this, saying "?" is not an allowed character.  appB requires the "?" to start it's query portion of the url.

My question is, does anyone know of a way (or an addon) that can do on the fly stream editing like sed?  I'd like to just replace the empty space " " with "?" every time that URL is launched.  We're using Firefox in our environment, so it would need to work with that. Preferably i'd be able to limit this behavior to only a certain domain or website.

edit:  As i've been doing some more searching, it seems like Greasemonkey might be my best bet for automatic URL modification?

Comment: In case anyone cares on this, I did find out a better way to achieve this.  Registering a new URI schema (a registry entry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT) that launches a helper script to modify the URL as necessary.  This gave us more flexibility.  Here are the relevant links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone cares on this, I did find out a better way to achieve this.  Registering a new URI scheme (a registry entry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT) that launches a helper script to modify the URL as necessary.  This gave us more flexibility to work with other sites if needed.

Here are the relevant links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so